# Excel - Incrementing

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out how to increment by 5 seconds.

The format I need to keep is:

0.00:00:00

So, what I'm looking for is:

```
0.00:00:00
0.00:00:05
0.00:00:10
```

once it gets to 1 minute it would be

```
0.00:01:00
0.00:01:05
```

etc.

I have been able to achieve this but only as format date and time, and I need it to be values but I don't know how to do it.

When I click on a cell it looks like this
[image]

I have a file where someone at some point was able to make it look like the image below, and this is what I'm looking for:
[image]

Comment: Why values? You talk about if it gets to 1 minute, so that sounds like time-formatting might just be fine. Why do you need values, and what do you exactly mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

In **A1** enter:

```
=TIME(0,0,(ROW()-1)*5)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Format as shown above.

Comment: I've edited my post. Thank you for your reply, but this isn't achieving what I need.  It is in a way, but incrementing 5 seconds, but I need it to not show date time when I click on the cell.  I need it to show as just a general number. Please see my edited post.

Comment: @Kristenl2784  The only way I can make the **Formula Bar** display as in your post is to use *VBA* to convert the cells from date/time to Text.

Comment: How do you go about this?

Comment: Hello,  I figured out how to convert the column to text without VBA. Thank you.